# Getting only the output of query without table shape

Tags: mysql

I use a query command from bash which returns a number. However, it is printed as a table.

```
$ mysql -u muser -p$PASS mm -e "SELECT.....;"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface  can be insecure.
+----------------------------+
| COUNT(DISTINCT ula.userid) |
+----------------------------+
|                         29 |
+----------------------------+
```

I just want to get 29 and append that to a file with `>> file.txt`. How can I do that in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `skip-column-names` and `batch-mode` with `-N` and `-B` respectively:

```
mysql -u muser -p$PASS mm -NBe "SELECT.....;" >> file.txt
```

Comment: You can append to an existing file? - didn't know that